# .editorconfig is not working in Visual Studio 2017 when my sotution is not in my C: drive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-community, editorconfig

I have added a `.editorconfig` file at my solution base folder but Visual Studio 2017 keeps using its settings, but this happenes just when the solution folder is not in the C: drive (if the solution folder is in the C: drive `.editorconfig` file is working perfectly).

I have also tried to add `.editorconfig` file to each project of the solution but still the same problem.

Note that I have `root = true` in my `.editorconfig` file.

I am using the following version of Visual Studio:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.2 (26430.06)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow figured out how to solve this problem.

My solution folder had a parent folder named between square brackets `[]` like this `[ParentFolderName]` so I removed the square brackets and everything worked as expected.

For a reason or another editorconfig file does not do anything when the solution folder has a parent folder named between square brackets. The IDE (in my case Visual Studio 2017) uses its settings.