.editorconfig being overridden by local code style preferences in Visual Studio 2017
I've recently been setting up our team coding standards in .editorconfig styles as an alternative to ReSharper. This morning I've been driving myself insane because nothing I try will get the styles to apply when and where they should. I've seen so many other threads and nothing has solved the problem. This question is closest to my problem, but was never resolved.
Our limitations:

Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.4)
.NET 4.8
We need to load solutions with devenv MySolution.sln /useenv

I've reduced my .editorconfig file to four rules, with no set severity to make things simple to test. (And also because I wasn't sure if something else in the file was breaking it.) So this is all that's in the current file (at the same level as the .sln file, included as a solution item):
# To learn more about .editorconfig see https://aka.ms/editorconfigdocs

############################### 
# .NET Coding Conventions     # 
############################### 
[*.{cs}] 
# this. preferences 
dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = true
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = true
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = true
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = true

My personal/machine-specific settings are the opposite:

Because .editorconfig files are supposed to override personal settings, I would expect Intellisense to be happy with 'this' keywords and not remove them when formatting the document. Instead I get the lightbulb telling me I can simplify the name by removing 'this':

And when I format the document, it just removes them. So VS2017 is clearly just ignoring the .editorconfig file. VS2022 and VSCode both respect the settings (though this wasn't using devenv).
Things I have tried:

Making sure my folder hierarchy doesn't contain square brackets
Adding root = true
Adding at the project level as well as/in addition to the solution level
Changing the severity level
Putting .editorconfig right at the top level of my repository
Some other things I didn't note down, like adding some specific lines to the .csproj files

Does anyone know what I'm missing or how I can get this working?

You are right; normally, .editorconfig should override personal settings. Based on your description, it seems like the configuration file is not taking effect. I recommend that you check the "Follow project coding conventions" option in
Tools > Options > Text Editor
.

@ZhenningZhang Ah, that's one of the things I forgot I tried. I have that box ticked already, but it doesn't seem to take effect.

See also the VS documentation for editorconfig (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022)which mentions: "When you add an EditorConfig file to your project in Visual Studio, new lines of code are formatted based on the EditorConfig settings. The formatting of existing code isn't changed unless you run one of the following commands: Code Cleanup, Format Document"

And see this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079291/editorconfig-is-not-working-in-visual-studio-2017-when-my-sotution-is-not-in-my?rq=3
My solution folder had a parent folder named between square brackets [] like this [ParentFolderName] so I removed the square brackets and everything worked as expected.
For a reason or another editorconfig file does not do anything when the solution folder has a parent folder named between square brackets. The IDE (in my case Visual Studio 2017) uses its settings.

Apologies for taking a while to reply – I was away for a while. I have read the documentation and had already seen the question that was resolved by removing square brackets. My path doesn't contain them. I have got slightly closer to it working by including some extra properties relating to code analysis in my csproj, but I'm now left with warnings about a dependency on netstandard 2.0.0.0 which I can't find a good solution to.  If I manage to sort out those warnings, I'll post an answer with the full steps, but no dice so far.

Did you ever get this to work?  In my experience, editorconfig only begins to (barely) work if you migrate from legacy-style project files to sdk-style project files. See michael.gr - Converting MSBuild project files from legacy-style to SDK-style

Also, in my experience, visual studio support for editorconfig is extremely finicky, and anything that goes wrong is treated with silent failure, which is a deadly combination: it won't work and it won't tell you why it won't work. Things to try: with or without UTF BOM, with CRLF or with LF for newlines, with an extra newline at the end of the file, etc.
